# Moving a chat server application from parse.com to google app engine

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, parse-platform

We are planning to move a chat server application resides on parse.com to Google app engine's datastore since parse is going to shutdown it's service on  Jan 2017. I think this should be possible through [App engine's XMPP API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp). Not sure, I love to hear from you..

Currently I'm testing with this code provided by [Google](https://github.com/googlearchive/appengine-crowdguru-python)

```
# Copyright 2009 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""Crowdguru sample application using the XMPP service on Google App Engine."""



import datetime

from google.appengine.api import datastore_types
from google.appengine.api import xmpp
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import xmpp_handlers
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import jinja2



PONDER_MSG = 'Hmm. Let me think on that a bit.'
TELLME_MSG = 'While I\'m thinking, perhaps you can answer me this: {}'
SOMEONE_ANSWERED_MSG = ('We seek those who are wise and fast. One out of two '
                        'is not enough. Another has answered my question.')
ANSWER_INTRO_MSG = 'You asked me: {}'
ANSWER_MSG = 'I have thought long and hard, and concluded: {}'
WAIT_MSG = ('Please! One question at a time! You can ask me another once you '
            'have an answer to your current question.')
THANKS_MSG = 'Thank you for your wisdom.'
TELLME_THANKS_MSG = THANKS_MSG + ' I\'m still thinking about your question.'
EMPTYQ_MSG = 'Sorry, I don\'t have anything to ask you at the moment.'
HELP_MSG = ('I am the amazing Crowd Guru. Ask me a question by typing '
            '\'/tellme the meaning of life\', and I will answer you forthwith! '
            'To learn more, go to {}/')
MAX_ANSWER_TIME = 120


class IMProperty(ndb.StringProperty):
    """A custom property for handling IM objects.

    IM or Instant Message objects include both an address and its protocol. The
    constructor and __str__ method on these objects allow easy translation from
    type string to type datastore_types.IM.
    """

    def _validate(self, value):
        """Validator to make sure value is an instance of datastore_types.IM.

        Args:
            value: The value to be validated. Should be an instance of
                datastore_types.IM.

        Raises:
            TypeError: If value is not an instance of datastore_types.IM.
        """
        if not isinstance(value, datastore_types.IM):
            raise TypeError('expected an IM, got {!r}'.format(value))

    def _to_base_type(self, value):
        """Converts native type (datastore_types.IM) to datastore type (string).

        Args:
            value: The value to be converted. Should be an instance of
                datastore_types.IM.

        Returns:
            String corresponding to the IM value.
        """
        return str(value)

    def _from_base_type(self, value):
        """Converts datastore type (string) to native type (datastore_types.IM).

        Args:
            value: The value to be converted. Should be a string.

        Returns:
            String corresponding to the IM value.
        """
        return datastore_types.IM(value)



class Question(ndb.Model):
    """Model to hold questions that the Guru can answer."""
    question = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    asker = IMProperty(required=True)
    asked = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now_add=True)
    suspended = ndb.BooleanProperty(required=True)

    assignees = IMProperty(repeated=True)
    last_assigned = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

    answer = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=True)
    answerer = IMProperty()
    answered = ndb.DateTimeProperty()


    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def _try_assign(key, user, expiry):
        """Assigns and returns the question if it's not assigned already.

        Args:
            key: ndb.Key: The key of a Question to try and assign.
            user: datastore_types.IM: The user to assign the question to.
            expiry: datetime.datetime: The expiry date of the question.

        Returns:
            The Question object. If it was already assigned, no change is made.
        """
        question = key.get()
        if not question.last_assigned or question.last_assigned < expiry:
            question.assignees.append(user)
            question.last_assigned = datetime.datetime.now()
            question.put()
        return question

    @classmethod
    def assign_question(cls, user):
        """Gets an unanswered question and assigns it to a user to answer.

        Args:
            user: datastore_types.IM: The identity of the user to assign a
                question to.

        Returns:
            The Question entity assigned to the user, or None if there are no
                unanswered questions.
        """
        question = None
        while question is None or user not in question.assignees:
            # Assignments made before this timestamp have expired.
            expiry = (datetime.datetime.now()
                      - datetime.timedelta(seconds=MAX_ANSWER_TIME))

            # Find a candidate question
            query = cls.query(cls.answerer == None, cls.last_assigned < expiry)
            # If a question has never been assigned, order by when it was asked
            query = query.order(cls.last_assigned, cls.asked)
            candidates = [candidate for candidate in query.fetch(2)
                          if candidate.asker != user]
            if not candidates:
                # No valid questions in queue.
                break

            # Try and assign it
            question = cls._try_assign(candidates[0].key, user, expiry)

        # Expire the assignment after a couple of minutes
        return question

    @ndb.transactional
    def unassign(self, user):
        """Unassigns the given user from this question.

        Args:
            user: datastore_types.IM: The user who will no longer be answering
                this question.
        """
        question = self.key.get()
        if user in question.assignees:
            question.assignees.remove(user)
            question.put()

    @classmethod
    def get_asked(cls, user):
        """Returns the user's outstanding asked question, if any.

        Args:
            user: datastore_types.IM: The identity of the user asking.

        Returns:
            An unanswered Question entity asked by the user, or None if there
                are no unanswered questions.
        """
        query = cls.query(cls.asker == user, cls.answer == None)
        return query.get()

    @classmethod
    def get_answering(cls, user):
        """Returns the question the user is answering, if any.

        Args:
            user: datastore_types.IM: The identity of the user answering.

        Returns:
            An unanswered Question entity assigned to the user, or None if there
                are no unanswered questions.
        """
        query = cls.query(cls.assignees == user, cls.answer == None)
        return query.get()



def bare_jid(sender):

    """Identify the user by bare jid.

    See http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Jabber_Resources for more details.

    Args:
        sender: String; A jabber or XMPP sender.

    Returns:
        The bare Jabber ID of the sender.
    """

    return sender.split('/')[0]


class XmppHandler(xmpp_handlers.CommandHandler):
    """Handler class for all XMPP activity."""


    def unhandled_command(self, message=None):
        """Shows help text for commands which have no handler.

        Args:
            message: xmpp.Message: The message that was sent by the user.
        """
        message.reply(HELP_MSG.format(self.request.host_url))


    def askme_command(self, message=None):
        """Responds to the /askme command.

        Args:
            message: xmpp.Message: The message that was sent by the user.
        """
        im_from = datastore_types.IM('xmpp', bare_jid(message.sender))
        currently_answering = Question.get_answering(im_from)
        question = Question.assign_question(im_from)
        if question:
            message.reply(TELLME_MSG.format(question.question))
        else:
            message.reply(EMPTYQ_MSG)
        # Don't unassign their current question until we've picked a new one.
        if currently_answering:
            currently_answering.unassign(im_from)



    def text_message(self, message=None):
        """Called when a message not prefixed by a /cmd is sent to the XMPP bot.

        Args:
            message: xmpp.Message: The message that was sent by the user.
        """
        im_from = datastore_types.IM('xmpp', bare_jid(message.sender))
        question = Question.get_answering(im_from)
        if question:
            other_assignees = question.assignees
            other_assignees.remove(im_from)

            # Answering a question
            question.answer = message.arg
            question.answerer = im_from
            question.assignees = []
            question.answered = datetime.datetime.now()
            question.put()

            # Send the answer to the asker
            xmpp.send_message([question.asker.address],
                              ANSWER_INTRO_MSG.format(question.question))
            xmpp.send_message([question.asker.address],
                              ANSWER_MSG.format(message.arg))

            # Send acknowledgement to the answerer
            asked_question = Question.get_asked(im_from)
            if asked_question:
                message.reply(TELLME_THANKS_MSG)
            else:
                message.reply(THANKS_MSG)

            # Tell any other assignees their help is no longer required
            if other_assignees:
                xmpp.send_message([user.address for user in other_assignees],
                                  SOMEONE_ANSWERED_MSG)
        else:
            self.unhandled_command(message)



    def tellme_command(self, message=None):
        """Handles /tellme requests, asking the Guru a question.

        Args:
            message: xmpp.Message: The message that was sent by the user.
        """
        im_from = datastore_types.IM('xmpp', bare_jid(message.sender))
        asked_question = Question.get_asked(im_from)

        if asked_question:
            # Already have a question
            message.reply(WAIT_MSG)
        else:
            # Asking a question
            asked_question = Question(question=message.arg, asker=im_from)
            asked_question.put()

            currently_answering = Question.get_answering(im_from)
            if not currently_answering:
                # Try and find one for them to answer
                question = Question.assign_question(im_from)
                if question:
                    message.reply(TELLME_MSG.format(question.question))
                    return
            message.reply(PONDER_MSG)




class XmppPresenceHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """Handler class for XMPP status updates."""

    def post(self, status):
        """POST handler for XMPP presence.

        Args:
            status: A string which will be either available or unavailable
               and will indicate the status of the user.
        """
        sender = self.request.get('from')
        im_from = datastore_types.IM('xmpp', bare_jid(sender))
        suspend = (status == 'unavailable')
        query = Question.query(Question.asker == im_from,
                               Question.answer == None,
                               Question.suspended == (not suspend))
        question = query.get()
        if question:
            question.suspended = suspend
            question.put()



class LatestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """Displays the most recently answered questions."""

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        """Cached property holding a Jinja2 instance.

        Returns:
            A Jinja2 object for the current app.
        """
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_response(self, template, **context):
        """Use Jinja2 instance to render template and write to output.

        Args:
            template: filename (relative to $PROJECT/templates) that we are
                rendering.
            context: keyword arguments corresponding to variables in template.
        """
        rendered_value = self.jinja2.render_template(template, **context)
        self.response.write(rendered_value)

    def get(self):
        """Handler for latest questions page."""
        query = Question.query(Question.answered > None).order(
                -Question.answered)
        self.render_response('latest.html', questions=query.fetch(20))



APPLICATION = webapp2.WSGIApplication([

        ('/', LatestHandler),

        ('/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/', XmppHandler),
        ('/_ah/xmpp/presence/(available|unavailable)/', XmppPresenceHandler),
        ], debug=True)
```

If a user selects another user whom he wants to chat with should call  API url `/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/` which automatically invokes `XmppHandler` handler.

```
 ('/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/', XmppHandler)
```

And my doubt is, If he post a message like `foo` on that particular chat does it automatically invokes  `text_message` method exists in `XmppHandler` ? Is there we need to configure xmpp on client side also?

Comment: seems too broad for s.o.. what have you tried so far? whats failing?  what issues you suspect? xmpp seems like just small part of your migration.

Comment: @ZigMandel updated...

Comment: Guys, I'm not asking about migration.. I'm just trying to test the above server code with a client code.. Pls provide some android client code.. Don't know whether the sending and receiving messages through the server should work instantly or not..

Comment: question is too broad. xmpp its a small issue compared with all you will need. one answer already posted a detailed guide to move parse to appengine.

Comment: @Zig Mandel forget about parse migration. I need to create an android chat app which should work with gae. Does the above code will work if I made post requests from that app?

Comment: try it and let us know what went wrong exactly. otherwise the question is too broad per guidelines. also, consider firebase.

Comment: @ZigMandel I think you could be able to answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653184/gae-xmpp-app-shows-invalid-jid-error)

Answer (score 3):

For the client api compatible and db migration, you can host your own parse-server.

There is a simple express project to use parse-server.
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

They are lots of deploy guide to each cloud-platform

[Google App Engine](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-parse-server-to-google-app-engine-6bc0b7451d50#.pzbcnnnjn)

[Heroku and mLab](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku)

[AWS and Elastic Beanstalk](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk)

[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[NodeChef](https://nodechef.com/blog/post/6/migrate-from-parse-to-nodechef%E2%80%99s-managed-parse-server)

[Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/)

[Pivotal Web Services](https://github.com/cf-platform-eng/pws-parse-server)

[Back4app](http://blog.back4app.com/2016/03/01/quick-wizard-migration/)

Or you can host your nodejs server with your domain name.

If you want to do something different from parse, you can send a pull request to [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server). [LiveQuery](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-LiveQuery) is the extra function created by contributors.

For more details, see the link from [Parse.com](https://parse.com/migration) , [github wiki](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki), and [community links](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki#community-links).

Comment: do you have any idea regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653184/gae-xmpp-app-shows-invalid-jid-error ?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with GAE, python, xmpp.

Answer (score 1):

> Parse has provided [detailed information](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-parse-server-to-google-app-engine-6bc0b7451d50#.rxdprcf4g) regarding the migration
>   process and how to move our app from their serviers to a seperately
>   hosted mongoDB instance and cloud company. Parse suggests the
>   migration be made in two steps:
>
> - The database is migrated to a service like MongoLab or ObjectRocket.
> - The server be migrated to a cloud hosting company like AWS, Google    App Engine, or Heroku.

Parse has also put suggested deadlines in place:

> they suggest that by April 28, 2016 the database be migrated and by
>   July 28, 2016, the server be migrated properly.

This will give you ample time to work out any bugs and ensure your app functions properly with no downtime!

A `Backend-as-a-Service` like `parse.com` coupled two aspects of what’s known as a backend into one: the `server` and `database`. The server, which manipulates the database, performs queries, fetches information, and other work-intensive tasks, interacts with the database. The two work hand-in-hand to form a backend.

> With Parse going away, we must deal with the server and database
>   seperately.

Parse has already provided [detailed info and easy migration tool](https://parse.com/migration#database) for database to Mongodb hosted on any cloud.

Also it is easy to setup the node based parse server on any cloud platform including Google App Engine:

The easiest way to get Parse server running on Google Cloud is to start with the [sample out on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples.git).

[image]